# AngularJs dividing list in two div

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I have a list of elements which I am displaying in a div tag which is inside a sidebar. the list contains lot of elements and I am planning to display the list of items in two columns rather in a single div tag.

In Angularjs, how can we divide the list into two sections so that I can display the list in two divs?

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6" >
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <li ng-repeat="tag in primTags"><a ng-click="select(tag.tagId, tag.name)">{{tag.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6" >
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you add some code example

Comment: how do you want to divide the list?  by some property or some other logic?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, ignore my other answer. That is the naive non-reusable way.

The *angular way* of doing this is to use a filter. Why? Because we're not actually changing the meaning of the data, just presenting it differently.

So we want to filter `$scope.list` into evenly divided lists.

```
app.filter('columns', function() {
  return function(val, col) {
    return val.filter(function(v) {
      if (val.indexOf(v) % 2 === col) {
        return true
      }
    })
  }
})
```

First of all, this is just a two column filter. You can use the same technique to make `n` columns, but this is just a simple solution for the problem at hand.

Now in our template, we can do:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list | columns:0">{{item}}</li>
```

That way, we don't have to repeat ourselves by maintaining three sets of lists or setup any `$watch` functions. Just update `list`, and the UI updates.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3K2g/6/

Comment: To be pedantic, you should actually use `angular.module` to creature a filter, as per [this Angular docs page](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
$scope.sublistA = $scope.list.map(function(listItem) { return listItem.propertyA; });
$scope.sublistB = $scope.list.map(function(listItem) { return listItem.propertyB; });
```

Then just ng-repeat over the two $scope sublists.

Comment: you mean populate the two list equally and set in the scope and then use them in the ui?

Comment: Yes. You could also just move your ng-repeat to a div that encloses both lists, and populate them by tag.whatever individually. I'm still not entirely sure I get what you are trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to sort the list equally, you can just maintain two separate lists on your controller as @aet said — however, you need to use `$scope.$watchCollection` if you want them to stay up to date.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('list', function(newVal) {
    var a = [], b = [], newLength = newVal.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < newLength; i++) {   
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            a.push(newVal[i])
        } else {
            b.push(newVal[i])
        }
    }
    $scope.listA = a;
    $scope.listB = b;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Kzs9/1/

(You could most certainly improve the performance and optimize this code)

Answer (score 0):

Although I initially used Jon Jaques' answer, I realize that Angular actually uses a different syntax (and style) for this.

Here's what a filter looks like, that assumes two columns, and filters a list of items to return only odd or even items:

```
app.filter('columnFilter', function()
{
    return function(items, columnNumber)
    {                   
        var toReturn = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == columnNumber)
            {
                toReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
});
```